# PayPal 'Buy Now' button option - how to access?

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I am adding a PayPal "Buy Now" button to a web site using code supplied by the PayPal developer site. It's possible to have options, for example garment sizes, XL,L,M,S... I see how to set up the button so the user can make a choice, but how do I access the choice so that I can take action? Is this supposed to be done in HTML, or should I write a CGI program to take my action - this is my preferred option - but either way, how can I access the option values? I am new to all this, but I can't find anything in the PayPal Developer documentation.

Comment: It is all specified in excruciating detail in the IPN guide.

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily done. Please look at the follow sample implementation and the source code for setting a Multi option based button.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside